# How to stop spam traffic and invalid activity on my website?

Tags: spam

I’m using a self-hosted wordpress blog since many years. Its a popular blog and I’m using Adsense ad units on it.

I checked my Webmasters Tools -> Search Traffic -> Links to your site list and I was surprised to see several spam/referral websites listed there which had no real backlinks towards my website.

I have used disavow tool in Webmasters Tools to disavow these domains. I have also tried to block these domains from reaching my website using `.htaccess` methods mentioned on a few websites but I’m not sure whether it’ll stop them or not.

Now I want to know is there any .htaccess or other method to prevent such kind of activities from happening again?

Can some method block these bots/spam referral links automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Try this [WP-ban](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ban/) WordPress plugin. It will display a custom ban message when the banned IP, IP range, host name or referrer url tries to visit you blog. You can also exclude certain IPs from being banned. There will be statistics recorded on how many times they attempt to visit your blog. It allows wildcard matching too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using .htaccess code to block referrers. Is there any plug-in which can automatically block spambots, spam referrers, etc?

Answer (score 2):

This is dangerously like a product recommendation, which is probably why you have two close votes, but...

I've had good luck with [Bad Behavior](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bad-behavior/), but there are lots of other [referrer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/referrer/) and [spam](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/spam/) plugins that might be worth looking into.  [Akismet](https://wordpress.org/plugins/akismet/) is really popular as well.